# How to cache a xml file when I use XmlDataSource1 control?

Tags: asp.net

I use MenuXML.xml file as datasource of XmlDataSource control in my MasterPage.master, it will be reloaded again and again.
could you tell me how to cache the  xml file? Thanks!

Comment: And more, will the website load more faster if I use the following code?  <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" XPath="Menu/Introduction/Item">
                    <Data>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Menu>  
  <Home>
    <Item Title="Overview"  ToolTip="Overview"  Url="www.hicalc.com" />
    <Item Title="Expression Calculation"   Url="~/FullExpress.aspx"/>
    <Item Title="Press Release"   />
    <Item Title="Recommend" ToolTip="Recommend The Website To Friends"  Url="~/Recommend.aspx" />
  </Home>  
</Menu></Data>
                </asp:XmlDataSource>

Answer (score 1):

XmlDataSource supports caching the file - see [EnableCaching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.enablecaching.aspx) property. For example,

```
 <asp:xmldatasource
        id="XmlDataSource1"
        runat="server"
        datafile="MenuXML.xml"
        enablecaching="True"
        cacheduration="0" />
```

Above will cache file content till the file is changed. I will suggest you to keep your menus externalized in a separate file (as opposed to putting them directly in markup) as it will reduce clutter (and allow you to switch/change file to change menus if needed).

Comment: Thanks!
Do you think it will be more faster if I put xml content into <Data><?xml version="1.0" ...</Data> ?

Comment: @Paul, not really - the file will be read for the first time and then cached in memory for all subsequent requests. So all it means that you will save time only in the first request (and that too a very minute time spent in file i/o).

Comment: Thanks! If I host my website on a shared hosting, maybe OS system often clear cache, so I think it will be more faster if I put xml content into <Data><?xml version="1.0" ...</Data> ? is it right?

Comment: @Paul, the said caching is not done by OS but rather by the control itself - so control will be essentially maintain the copy of xml in memory. The cache will be invalidate only when web application restarts (due to any reason such as config file change, pool recycle, IIS restart, machine restart etc).

Comment: Thanks!
Which is more faster between the xml file is read for the first time and stored in  <Data><?xml version="1.0" ...</Data>

Comment: @Paul, as said in answer, from performance point, both are really equivalent. You should decide from perspective from which organization is easier to maintain!